# Distinctly counting measure results that match a certain criteria

Tags: ssas, mdx

We have a measure for feedback scores which I am trying to report on. I need to calculate how many have reached a score >5 to calculate a performance %age. The issue I have is where there is more than one score available for my member which is aggregated in my results.

Here is what I have so far:

```
with
MEMBER [Client Sat Score] AS ([Measures].[Avg_Score], Linkmember([Bill Period].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Period].&[201409],[Date].[Fiscal]),[Bill Period].[Fiscal].[All],[Time Slice].[KeyTimeSlice].[12M])

MEMBER [Sum Scores] AS([Measures].[Sum of Scores], Linkmember([Bill Period].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Period].&[201409],[Date].[Fiscal]),[Bill Period].[Fiscal].[All],[Time Slice].[KeyTimeSlice].[12M])

MEMBER [Number Scores] AS([Measures].[Number of Scores], Linkmember([Bill Period].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Period].&[201409],[Date].[Fiscal]),[Bill Period].[Fiscal].[All],[Time Slice].[KeyTimeSlice].[12M])

MEMBER [Over 5] As IIF([Client Sat Score]>5,1,NULL)

MEMBER [Scores Over 5] As SUM([Matter].[KeyMatterNumber].[KeyMatterNumber].members,[Over 5])

MEMBER [Percent 6 or 7s] As IIF([Number Scores]=0,NULL,[Scores Over 5] / [Number Scores])


select {[Client Sat Score],[Sum Scores],[Number Scores],[Over 5],[Scores Over 5],[Percent 6 or 7s] }
on columns,

non empty ({[Client].[KeyClientRelatedID].&[XXX] })
on rows

from [Cube]
```

This returns 4 for "Scores over 5" but there are actually 2 scores of 7 on one of the members. These scores are on different date keys but I am unable to stop them aggregating within the SUM.

Any suggestions/advice please?

EDIT:

I've found that if I run the following I do get the 5 separate results each with a score above 5:

```
select {[Measures].[Avg_Score] }
on columns,

non empty ({[Matter].[KeyMatterNumber].[KeyMatterNumber].members })*
{[Date].[KeyDate].[KeyDate].&[20130206]:[Date].[KeyDate].[KeyDate].&[20140206]}
on rows

from [Cube]
where (
[Client].[KeyClientRelatedID].&[XXXX]
)
```

Does this help at all with the amendment of my first query?

Comment: Could you explain the design of your cube? I am not sure I understand your requirement without that. Probably, the solution would involve changing the cube to use a many-to-many-relationship, but to explain that I would have to know how the cube looks like currently (dimensions and measure groups relevant for this question).

Comment: Im not sure if you can change the Cube design, but a Distinct Count Measure on a Member ID or similar would probably work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've added another query that I found would list the 5 results and added to the original post. Mike, the [Number of Scores] measure is a count of scores but not distinct, does that help? Frank, I think all the relevant measures and groups are in the original post but please let me know if i can clarify anything.

Comment: Would `MEMBER [Scores Over 5] As DistinctCount(Filter([Matter].[KeyMatterNumber].[KeyMatterNumber].members, [Client Sat Score] > 5))` give what you want? Without seeing the real data, it is difficult to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to answer without a cube schema available. However, it sounds like you are trying to do a row level calculation post-aggregation which results in your attempts to find the combination of dimensions that will cause leaf level data to be used in the calculation. Even if possible these invariably perform badly.

I would suggest pushing this calculation into the underlying database and generating an additional dimension with banded values { [1-5], [6-7] }.

Also, you didn't mention if this Analysis Services (or another vendor) Multidimensional or Tabular - if Tabular just create a row calc for "Over 5" in the cube and use that as your new dimension members.